# Java Calendar add not incrementing year

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have a variable that stores the week start date, but when I go forward from 2012 to 2013 it doesn't update the year.

The day and month add properly, so it correctly goes from the 26/12 to 02/01 but it stays as 2012.

```
// roll one week forward
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(mPrefsHelper.getWeekStart());
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

Comment: It would be better if you check/debug the value of `mPrefsHelper.getWeekStart()`.

Comment: It would be better if you check/print/debug the value of your `mPrefsHelper.getWeekStart()` method.

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

From javadoc of [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> ```
> First Week
> ```
>
> Calendar defines a locale-specific seven day week using two parameters: the first day of the week and the minimal days in first
> week (from 1 to 7). These numbers are taken from the locale resource
> data when a Calendar is constructed. They may also be specified
> explicitly through the methods for setting their values.
>
> When setting or getting the WEEK_OF_MONTH or WEEK_OF_YEAR fields, Calendar must determine the first week of the month or year as a
> reference point. The first week of a month or year is defined as the
> earliest seven day period beginning on getFirstDayOfWeek() and
> containing at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days of that month or
> year. Weeks numbered ..., -1, 0 precede the first week; weeks numbered
> 2, 3,... follow it. Note that the normalized numbering returned by
> get() may be different. For example, a specific Calendar subclass may
> designate the week before week 1 of a year as week n of the previous
> year.

it is locale-specific. In your case, if the week contains days from new year, it is counted as week 1 from the new year.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, and thanks for all your responses. My problem was specific to my code, at some point I was doing this:

```
mCalendar.clear();
mCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

and using values that I obtained from the date I got with my previous code.

So it was getting a date (say Wed 2nd Jan) which has a week of 1 and a year of 2013. It clears the calendar and sets the week and year correctly, however I was then calling this bit again, which was setting the year to be 2012 somehow. I've basically removed this code in most scenarios and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use the `YearWeek` class from the *ThreeTen-Extra* library.

```
LocalDate firstDayOfFirstYearWeekOfNextWeekBasedYear =     // Represent a date-only value, without a time-of-day, without a time zone.
    YearWeek                                               // Represent an entire week of a week-based year using standard ISO 8601 definition of a week and year.
    .of(                                                   // Determine the year-week of a particular date.
        LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )   // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
    )                                                      // Returns a `YearWeek` object.
    .plusYears( 1 )                                        // Returns a `YearWeek` object representing the following year's year-week.
    .withWeek( 1 )                                         // Adjust to the first week of that week-based-year.
    .atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )                             // Determine the date of a day-of-week within that week. Returns a `LocalDate`. Remember, this might be a date in the *previous* calendar year.
;
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted years ago the troublesome legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`.

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.DECEMBER , 26 ) ;
```

### Next day-of-week

We use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) to move to another date. Several implementations are found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class. We want `next` which finds the next date for a certain day-of-week.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ;
```

Apply that to get the next date.

```
LocalDate nextWednesday = localDate.with( ta ) ;
```

> nextWednesday.toString(): 2013-01-02

Yes, we do see the year roll over from 2012 to 2013.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/0Bj1lT).

### Year-week

If you want a date found by ordinal week of the year, that is more complicated. You must define what you mean by week. Does week # 1 contain January 1st? Or is week # 1 the first week fully composed of days from the new year? Or does # 1 have certain day of the week in the new year?

#### ISO 8601 standard week

The standard [ISO 8601 definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) defines the first week as containing the first Thursday of the new year. So a week-based-year has either 52 or 53 weeks, runs Monday-Sunday, and may start/end with days from the previous/next calendar-year.

If this meets your need, I suggest adding the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project. This gives you the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.DECEMBER , 26 ) ) ;
YearWeek ywNext = yw.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
```

Get a day from that week.

```
LocalDate ld = ywNext.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

To get the first day of the first week of the week-based-year following any local date:

```
LocalDate ld = 
    YearWeek
    .of( someLocalDate )
    .plusYears( 1 )
    .withWeek( 1 )
    .atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) 
;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]